# How do i declare custom generated strings inside a while loop?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is to declare a certain amount of strings according to the amount of tokens a scanner scans in a single input, then have these strings equal the next input. This is what I'm trying:

```
int numberOfTokens = 0;

boolean mainLoop = true;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(mainLoop == true)
{
   while(input.hasNext())
   {
      String int(+ numberOfTokens) = input.next(); (this doesn't work)
      numberOfTokens += 1;
   }
}
```

I hope I made it clear of what I am trying to do. I tried using String arrays, but they won't work for what i'm trying to do. 
Thanks.

Comment: `I hope I made it clear of what I am trying to do` nope

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, yes; Also: Why doesn't arrays work? This seems like a Array-problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in `String int(+ numberOfTokens) = input.next();`?

Comment: Note that `while(mainLoop == true)` can be written as `while(mainLoop)`

Comment: That isn't supposed to work. I said that on the line. What I was trying to represent was how I wanted to declare a string with the name (int + value of   numberOfTokens). That wasn't an attempt of making it work. That was me representing what In was trying to do. As for why arrays won't work, I need to explain exactly what my program is doing.

Comment: @JavaNoob usually you cannot and don't need to create variables in runtime

Comment: My program is taking in a mathematical Equation, breaking each token down into three different categories (numbers, commands, variables), piecing it back together with that information according to the order it was typed in, computing it, and displaying the answer as a string. The commands include (+, -, x, /, ^, //, cr, =) // being nth root, and cr being clear recent(this should remove any custom generated strings).

Comment: @Lashane if I shouldn't need to declare variables in the runtime, is there a different way I could be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know in advance how many strings you will need to store then an array is a poor choice of data structure, at least during the input phase.  Use a `List` instead -- these keep the elements in order, yet expand as needed to accommodate new elements.  They are convenient to work with overall, but if you ultimately must get the strings in array form (e.g. because some external API requires that form) then it is easy to obtain the corresponding array.

For example:

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

while (input.hasNext()) {
    tokens.add(input.next());
    // a List keeps track of its own length
}
```

If you later wanted the array then you could do

```
String[] tokenArray = tokens.toArray(new String[0]);
```

The number of tokens recorded in the `List` is available at any time as `tokens.size()`, or after you convert to an array, as `tokenArray.length`.

In any event, you cannot create new variables at runtime in Java.

Comment: Bit of an error though, the variable has to be a type of ArrayList instead of List.

Comment: @JavaNoob, `List` is an interface that `ArrayList` implements, so you can assign an `ArrayList` to a variable of type `List`.  There are reasons to prefer declaring the variable with the more abstract `List` type, as I have done, but that would be a whole other discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[abc];
```

where **abc** is an integer you get from user

and then

```
myStringArray[index]  = input.next();
```

and **index** must be a valid number **between 0 and abc**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string variables, you should declare one variable like this before the while loop.

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while (input.hasNext()) {
  tokens.add(input.next());
}
```

You can then operate on the tokens, like this:

```
int n = tokens.size();

for (String token : tokens) {
  System.out.println(token);
}
```